# How do I install OpenCV without it upgrading my python version on Mac?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I tried to install opencv for Python 3.6.5 on Mac OS. I tried `brew install opencv`, but it updates my python version to 3.7.

I tried `brew pin python` and then tried the installation but it just fails as it can't update the dependency.

```
Error: You must `brew unpin python` as installing opencv requires the latest version of pinned dependencies
```

I don't want to use `pip install opencv-python` as I read somewhere that it is not official.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What does "official" mean. You can do`pip install opencv-python`, and if you want to include the contrib modules, you can do `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: As in both of them don't give the exact same package. Anyways I want to install it using brew or some other package manager